# staticmethod and recursion?

Tags: python, class, methods

I have following code:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        baz=self.bar(10)

    @staticmethod
    def bar(n):
        if n==0:
            return 'bar'
        else:
            return bar(n-1)
```

bar() as a recursive function it needs reference to itself. However, bar() is inside a class, and calling `return bar(n-1)` will not work, invoking `NameError: global name 'bar' is not defined`. How can I deal with this kind of situation? Should I change bar() to a class or instance method, allowing access to `self` or `cls`?

Comment: Does calling `Foo.bar(n-1)` in the recursive call help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An alternative to using a class method or calling the class by name (as shown by others) is to use a closure to hold the reference to the function:

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar():
        def bar(n):
            if n == 0:
               return "bar"
            return bar(n-1)
        return bar
    bar = staticmethod(bar())
```

The (minor) advantage is that this is somewhat less susceptible to breaking when names change. For example, if you have a reference to `Foo.bar` *inside* `bar`, this relies on `Foo` continuing to be a global name for the class that `bar` is defined in. Usually this is the case but if it isn't, then the recursive call breaks.

The `classmethod` approach will provide the method with a reference to the class, but the class isn't otherwise needed in the method, which seems inelegant. Using the closure will also be marginally faster because it isn't doing an attribute lookup on each call.

Answer (score 59):

You can refer to `bar` by prefixing it with the class name:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        baz=self.bar(10)

    @staticmethod
    def bar(n):
        if n==0:
            return 'bar'
        else:
            return Foo.bar(n-1)
```

Static methods are nothing but regular functions contained within the namespace of a class after all.

Alternatively, define `bar` as a regular function instead:

```
def bar(n):
    if n==0:
        return 'bar'
    else:
        return bar(n-1)

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        baz=bar(10)
```

which avoids the whole issue altogether.

Comment: @senderle: yeah, just a c&p error on my part. You need it in Python 3 too.

Comment: Actually the code runs correctly without it in Python 3 -- at least when called from `Foo` itself. (But I see that it doesn't work when called from a `Foo` instance.)

Comment: @senderle It works in Python 3 because there are no more "unbound method" wrappers which require `isinstance(self, DefiningClass)` on calling methods. One thing that only works with `@staticmethod` is calling the method on an instance (`Foo().bar(1)`).

Comment: @senderle: the first argument of a method is call `self` only by convention. Since `bar` accepts an argument named `n`, it'll be used as the instance-bound parameter instead. And Python 3 no longer enforces the first-parameter-of-a-class-function-must-be-an-instance check, calling `class.method(integer)` works without an error.

Answer (score 9):

What about that?

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        baz = self.bar(10)

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls, n):
        if n == 0:
            return 'bar'
        else:
            return cls.bar(n-1)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can define bar() outside of Foo and then bring it in as a staticmethod so that you get all of the benefits of it being a method of the class while not having to close it or reference the class itself. I have needed something like this for class inheritance reasons.

```
def bar(n):
    if n==0:
        return 'bar'
    else:
        return bar(n-1)

class Foo(object):
    bar = staticmethod(bar)
    def __init__(self):
        baz=self.bar(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the main goal is to run a recursive method, you can use plain methods for this.

I actually never saw the use for this until now. lets say you have integer thresholds you need to test, this pattern can be quite nice and easy: ( even though it can create a bit overheat, so be cautious)

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.baz = self.bar(n)

    def bar(self, n):
        if n < -10:
            return 'bar < -10'
        if n == -10:
            return 'bar -10 - -1'
        if n == 0:
            return 'bar 0 - 9'
        if n == 10:
            return 'bar 10 - 19'
        if n >= 20:
            return 'bar >= 20'
        return self.bar(n-1)
```